# jQuery URL options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using a jQuery based UI object, it's a tree list, **aciTree**.  The tree uses Ajax as the datasource.  If I give it a URL that returns the JSON everything works.  However I need to dynamically generate the JSON on the fly and feed it to the Ajax URL property.

This is the pattern:

```
$.ajax(url[, options])
```

I have tried the following

```
url: JSON.stringify(JSONObj)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean to generate the JSON and pass it via Ajax via the `data` parameter? I am confused how the JSON is used to generate the URL.

Comment: I'm not sure which option to use.  This is the API
ajax: {
            url: null,
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        dataSource: null,

Comment: You need to tell us which treeview plugin you are using.  Regardless, the "datasource" can probably be set to ajax, or something else, like a json object.  The URL property would apply to ajax.  Find the right method in your plugin documentation.

Comment: So does it take JSON as INPUT or give JSON as OUTPUT?  I would think you have to give it a URL (not JSON) and you'll get JSON back.  Right?

Comment: the Tree View is aciTree.  They don't show usage for dataSource in API documentation.

Comment: The aciTree samples show configuring a URL which will return JSON - no need to make the ajax call yourself. Can you post how you are configuring the aciTree and where your `$.ajax` call fits in?

Comment: Does my answer help or produce any error for you now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to submit data via AJAX.  In which case you would do something like:

```
$.ajax(url, {data: JSON.stringify(JSONObj), dataType: 'json'}}])
```

Using JSON to build your URL seems odd.  That can't be what you intended.  Otherwise you should add validation to verify that the JSON.stringify method returns what you need (a valid url).